# reminder_date in Laravel stores wrong date from created at

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am having trouble with from a quite a few days.   I have column as (I tried with `date`, `datetime`, `timestamp`):

```
$table->timestampTz('reminder_date')->nullable();
```

And then in model I have:

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'reminder_date',
];
```

But when I store this `created_at` is storing automatically in UTC (from my config) but `reminder_date` is storing wrong time, it is storing according to local time.

Anyone have any solution please let me know.

Comment: how do you insert `reminder_date`?  timestampTz format is `'Y-m-d H:i:sO'` so your inserted date should be `'Y-m-d H:i:sO'`

Comment: As I mentioned I used all types of dates.. this is just recent.. my format passed is 2020-07-03 12:25:00

Comment: When insert you can change your format to timestampTz as like `\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:sO', $request->reminder_date);`